# When do Sylow $p$ and Sylow $q$ subgroups commute?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Do $p$-Sylow and $q$-Sylow subgroups commute iff both are unique and thus normal? I know that one direction is true: namely that if the $p$-Sylow subgroup and the $q$-Sylow subgroup are normal in the group, that they commute.

My question: Is the other direction also true?

Comment: It is enough that only one of them is normal for them to commute.

Comment: I am especially interested in a specific case. Really I want to show that given a group $G$ of order $p(p+1)$ with $p+1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups, any given Sylow $p$-subgroup acts nontrivially on the set of non-id elements with order not $p$. If what you're saying is true then I don't think this is true.

Comment: It is, @Johann...but let's make sure we both have the same definitions: two subgroups $\;H\,,\,K\;$ of a group $\;G\;$ are said to commute if $$\;HK=KH\iff \forall\,h\in H\,,\,\,jk\in K\;\;\exists\,h'\in H\,,\,\,k\in K\;\;s.t.\;\;hk=k'h'\;$$ The above is what I meant with commuting subgroups.

Comment: @Timbuc I believe you intended to say more? :)

Comment: In fact, we know that if $\;H\,,\,K\le G\;$ ,then $\;HK\;$ is also a subgroup of $\;G\;\iff\; HK=KH\;$

Comment: One sufficient condition for the above is that **at least** one of the subgroups is normal.

Comment: @Timbuc I see. In that case what would you suggest I use to see that my group action is nontrivial?

Comment: @Timbuc That is, the group action of a Sylow p-subgroup of a group of order $p(p+1)$ on the non-id elts not of order $p$.

Comment: I'm not sure I even understood that part, @Johann : do you want to make some Sylow $\;p\,$- subgroup $\;P\; $ act on the set of all the elements of order different from $\;p\;$ which are not the unit? What action would that be?

Comment: @Timbuc by conjugation.

Comment: @Timbuc There are $p$ non trivial elements in the described group, not of order $p$, given that it has $p+1$ Sylow p-subgroups.

Comment: So have a group $\;G\,,\,\,|G|=p(p+1)\;$ with $\;p+1\;$ Sylow $\;p\,$- subgroups, which gives us $$(p+1)(p-1)=p^2-1$$ elements of order $\;p\;$ , leaving then $\;p+1\;$ elements of order *not* $\;p\;$ , right?

Comment: @Timbuc exactly.

Comment: Ok, just a minute.

Comment: Well, we have this interesting theorem: if $\;X:=\{\;\text{elements of order}\;p\;\}\setminus\{1\}\;$ , and $\;X^P:=\{ x\in X\;:\; x^p=x\;\;\forall\,p\in P\}\;$ , then 
$$\;|X^P|=|X|\pmod p\;$$

And then

$$|X^P|=p=0\pmod p$$

which means either zero or $\;p\;$ elements are fixed by the above action...So if you know exactly the action on some element we can already deduce what happens with all the rest!@

Comment: @Timbuc I can't really seem to grasp the specific action on any element in this particular group. Additionally, where did you find this theorem?

Comment: http://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/the-p-group-fixed-point-theorem/

Comment: @Timbuc that is to say, I can't tell where a Sylow $p$-subgroup conjugates elements not of order $p$. Further your theorem appears to apply to elements OF order p...

Comment: @Timbuc further it isn't obvious to me that the elements in my group not of order $p$ are of order some other prime, $q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: $G=S_3$, $p=2$ and $q=3$.